# Get word count from a string in Unicode (in any language)

Tags: java, string, unicode, multilingual, word-count

I want to get word count from a String. It's as simple as that. The catch is that the string can be in an unpredictable language.

So, I need a function of signature `int getWordCount(String)` with the following sample output -

```
getWordCount("供应商代发发货") => 7
getWordCount("This is a sentence") => 4
```

Any help on how to proceed would be appreciated :)

Comment: In the chinese(?) text is there a separator between the words?

Comment: No there's no separator. I copied the exact strings.

Comment: In that case I would attempt to find the language based on which unicode runes are used in the string. Then use that information to determine how the string should be parsed.

Comment: You could `.trim()` the original string then count the number of spaces using `Character.isSpaceChar()` while looping over the string's `.toCharArray()`, unfortunately in the first example there are no spaces.

Comment: The problem is that finding words in Chinese cannot be done by syntax.

Comment: There are seven CHARACTERS in your string but I think there are fewer WORDS (see my answer) as some words are made up of several characters. Unless you know Chinese you can't assume 1 Character = 1 Word

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The concept of "word" may be trivial or complex. Here is [Apache Stanbol](http://stanbol.apache.org/docs/trunk/components/enhancer/nlp/) Toolkit:

> Word Tokenization: The detection of single words is required by the
>   Stanbol Enhancer to process text. While this is trivial for most
>   languages it is a rather complex task for some eastern languages, e.g.
>   Chinese, Japanese, Korean. If not otherwise configured, Stanbol will
>   use whitespaces to tokenize words.

So if the concept of word is linguistic, rather than syntactic, you should use a [NLP toolkit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aNatural_language_processing_toolkits)

My preferred Java solution is [Apache's Open NLP](http://opennlp.apache.org/)

NOTE: 
I have used http://www.mdbg.net/chindict/chindict.php?page=worddict 
to tokenize your example. It implies there are 4 words not seven. I have cut and pasted (rather fragmented):

Original Text   Simplified
Pīnyīn
        English definition Add a new word to the dictionary     Traditional
HSK
供应商 
供应商
gōng​yìng​shāng​

supplier

供應商
代
代
dài​

to substitute / to act on behalf of others / to replace / generation / dynasty / age / period / (historical) era / (geological) eon

发
发
fā​

to send out / to show (one's feeling) / to issue / to develop / classifier for gunshots (rounds)

發
HSK 4

发
fà​

hair / Taiwan pr. [fa3]

髮
发货
发货
fā​huò​

to dispatch / to send out goods

發貨

These first three characters appear to form a single word.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think your approach is very logical. I'll try to find some toolkits now to see how I can work this out.

Comment: Good. You may wish to start with a PartOfSpeech Tagger which will detect nouns, verbs, etc. And there are almost certainly some online services which help to to explore your problem. And your overall problem is probably more complex than simply finding words.

Comment: Do you know an easy toolkit / service for this? May be a good word tokenizer?

Comment: I depends on what you want to do. Extract entities (nouns)? Translate to other human languages? Classify chunks of text? Personally I use OpenNLP as I use Java; NLTK is Python-based.

Comment: A Java API is what I am looking for. And currently my objective is nothing other than what is stated in the question. I need just the word count for now.

Answer (score 6):

The standard API provides the [BreakIterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/BreakIterator.html) for this sort of boundary analysis but the Oracle Java 7 locale support doesn't break the sample string.

When I used the [ICU4J](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/icu4j/) v51.1 [BreakIterator](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/boundaryanalysis/#four-types-of-breakiterator) it broke the sample into `[供应, 商代, 发, 发, 货]`.

```
// import com.ibm.icu.text.BreakIterator;
String sentence = "\u4f9b\u5e94\u5546\u4ee3\u53d1\u53d1\u8d27";
BreakIterator iterator = BreakIterator.getWordInstance(Locale.CHINESE);
iterator.setText(sentence);

List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
int start = iterator.first();
int end = iterator.next();
while (end != BreakIterator.DONE) {
  words.add(sentence.substring(start, end));
  start = end;
  end = iterator.next();
}
System.out.println(words);
```

*Note: I used Google Translate to guess that "供应商代发发货" was Chinese. Obviously, I don't speak the language so can't comment on the correctness of the output.*

Comment: I tested this for several languages, including Chinese, Japanese, English, French, Spanish, and German, and it works flawlessly! One thing to consider for space-tokenized languages like English, French, etc., is whether or not to ignore spaces and punctuation in the tokenization. I don't count spaces and punctuation as 'words', so I explicitly remove these in the `List<String> words` after everything is tokenized by using the following regex: `Pattern spacesAndPunctuation = Pattern.compile("[\\p{P} \\t\\n\\r]")`

Comment: But how do you get "\u4f9b\u5e94\u5546\u4ee3\u53d1\u53d1\u8d27" from the original sentence?

Answer (score 2):

If we assume that every language has one (or more) word separator, and you can build regex for those separator, then the problem can be solved like this:

```
    public String separatorForLanguage(char unicodeChar){
        // Find out in which language unicodeChar falls  
        return ""; // return regex of separator of that language
    }

    public int wordCount(String sentance){
        char unicodeChar = sentance.charAt(0);
        String separator = separatorForLanguage(unicodeChar);

        int count = sentance.split(separator).length;
        if (separator.isEmpty()) {
            count--;
        }

        return count;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually, the Chinese / Japanese text doesn't have a separator and that's the problem.

Comment: @jaibatrik: then the separator is an empty string, i suppose.

Answer (score 2):

Here is snippet in java

```
public static int getWordCount(String string)
{
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[\\w']+|[\\u3400-\\u4DB5\\u4E00-\\u9FCC]");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
    int count = 0;
    while(matcher.find())
        count++;
    return count;                                   
}
```

Example

```
//count is 5
int wordCount = getWordCount("this is popcorny's 電腦");
```

Answer (score 1):

**English version**

For the English version you can do with a rather simple Regex. I may have missed some custom separators but:

```
public static int getWordCount(String str) {
    return str.split("[\\s,;-]+").length;
}
```

**Regex explanation:**

Split if find any in the group `[]`:

```
[
\\s Any whitespace character or
, A comma
; or a semi-colon
]
+ Followed by any patterns in the group any number of times
```

**Chinese version**

For the Chinese version, you need to identify what the separators are. If you get the Unicode char code of the Chinese separators and add them to the above regex, you will get the desired results.

**Tests**

```
System.out.println(getWordCount("This is a sentence"));// 4
System.out.println(getWordCount("This is a sentence")); // 4
System.out.println(getWordCount("This is a     ,,sentence")); // 4
```